# Node UIView OnSelect function

Tags: iphone, uiview, touch

I have a Node.m which is UIView, and I also have Gridview.m and Gridview consists of many node.m.   Inside the node.m there's a function which is activated when the user touches one of the nodes inside the Gridview.

Inside Node.m

```
- (void) onSelect:(id)sender
```

So, does that mean the onSelect is an innate function of UIView? If not, how does the onSelect function get associated with the touch event?

Comment: No, onSelect is not an innate function of UIView.  Maybe it's bound from Interface Builder.  Who wrote that code?

Comment: I don't see any xib files associcated with the node.m or gridview.m. Somebody wrote the code and compiled and runs correctly, in the gridview, anytime I hit one of the node(UIView) the onSelect function got called.

Comment: Ok, my bad, there's button associated with this view. onSelect called when the button or this UIview is hit.

Answer (score 0):

Search your entire project (<kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd>) for 'onSelect' to see where it is being called.